# CSRF payload delivery

Tags: attacks, csrf, web

If an attacker successfully delivers a CSRF payload by any means, what response can he can see once a victim clicks the link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None, generally, unless the target site changes in a way that the attacker can detect. CSRF is generally a blind attack; the attacker gets no more feedback that a victim clicked the link or loaded the page than they would about anybody on the internet clicking a link or loading a page on some site that both had visited.

There are some possible exceptions, though:

1. If the origin of the attack is controlled by the attacker (say, their own personal site), they can put script in that notifies the attacker before attempting the attack. It's not possible to tell whether the attack succeeded - same-origin policy prevents that - but it's possible to tell when it started if you can control scripting around it.
2. If the attacker is in a position to monitor the victim's network traffic, then it will be possible to determine the extent of the victim's interaction with the target site. Intercepting the actual HTTP is probably impossible, since it will be protected by TLS, but TLS doesn't hide how much traffic is sent each way, or the timing of the request and response. That might be enough to infer whether the attack succeeded.
3. If the target site changed in some detectable way, this may be visible to the attacker. Some simple toy examples: if you use CSRF to force somebody to tweet a message, you could see the message they posted. If you use CSRF to force somebody to transfer money to your account, you'll be able to see the incoming transfer.